# Display MongoDB collections using HTML file

Tags: php, html, mongodb

i am trying to display data from mongoDB with HTNL but the code that i wrote doesn't do it and i have no clue what i should change so it will work.

```
<body>
<?php
    $server = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient($server);
   // select a database
   $db = $m->test;
?>

    try{
        // Connecting to server
    $c = new MongoClient( $server );
    }catch(MongoConnectionException $connectionException){
        print $connectionException;
        exit;
    }

    $data  = "<table style='border:1px solid red;";
    $data .= "border-collapse:collapse' border='1px'>";
    $data .= "<thead>";
    $data .= "<tr>";
    $data .= "<th>Name</th>";
    $data .= "<th>UserID</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Email</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Sites Links</th>";
    $data .= "<th>Imgaes</th>"
    $data .= "</tr>";
    $data .= "</thead>";
    $data .= "<tbody>";

    try{
        $collection = $db->links;
        $people = $collection->find();
        foreach($people as $document){
            $data .= "<tr>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["Name_of_the_person"] . "</td>"; // Name
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["userID"]."</td>"; // UserID
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["email"]."</td>"; // Email
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["links"]."</td>"; // Sites
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["imagesurl"]."</td>"; // Images
            $data .= "</tr>";
        }
        $data .= "</tbody>";
        $data .= "</table>";
        echo $data;

    }catch(MongoException $mongoException){
        print $mongoException;
        exit;
    }

</body>
</html>
```

i would really want to know what is wrong with the code.

Thanks

Comment: Because the ?> tag is in the wrong position?

Comment: So where should i put it?

Comment: Where your php ends?

Comment: After I connect to the db I think. I need to display the data that is saved inside this data base but I don't know how..

Comment: You need not have to write code to do this. Start mongoDB with --rest , you can query data from the REST API(though not in the format mentioned by you)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with vmr's comment. But if you still want to use the code:

```
<?php
$server = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
// connect to mongodb
$m = new MongoClient($server);
// select a database
$db = $m->test;

?>

<table style='border:1px solid red border-collapse:collapse' border='1px'>";
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UserID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Sites Links</th>
            <th>Images</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>


<?php
try{
    $collection = $db->links;
    $people = $collection->find();
    foreach($people as $document){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$document["Name_of_the_person"]."</td>"; // Name
       echo "<td>".$document["userID"]."</td>"; // UserID
       echo "<td>".$document["email"]."</td>"; // Email
       echo "<td>".$document["links"]."</td>"; // Sites
       echo "<td>".$document["imagesurl"]."</td>"; // Images
       echo "</tr>";
   }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}catch(MongoException $mongoException){
   print $mongoException;
   exit;
}
?>
```

I know the post is old. But if you are still looking for the solution it might help.